# Percorrer todas as propriedades de um objeto VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, objetos, replace

Estou usando VueJS em um projeto e preciso percorrer todas as propriedades do objeto associado ao `v-model`.

Sei que se fosse um array eu poderia usar u `for`, `foreach`,
`map` e muitos outros meios de percorrer ele.

Mas o que eu preciso fazer é o seguinte: Percorrer todas as propriedades de um objeto e efetuar um `replace()` somente nas propriedades que contenha `/`, `-`, `.`,`(`, `)`, pois esse caracteres são provenientes das máscaras que foram usadas nos `input`'s, e não quero salvar esses caracteres no banco de dados.

Se eu estivesse usando a biblioteca de máscaras como componente eu conseguiria fazer com que o valor saísse sem os caracteres em questão, porém estou usando a biblioteca de máscaras como uma diretiva `v-mask`, e o valor que vem do `input` é sempre com a máscara.

Já pesquisei bastante mas ainda não achei um método eficiente de resolver esse problema, se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço...

Obs.: É uma exigência do projeto que os `input` não sejam o `v-mask` sendo usado como componente, pois eles foram customizados e é uma exigência usar eles

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo mais concreto? ou mostrar o código que tens para percebermos melhor?

Comment: Digamos que eu tenha a propriedade `cep` `cpf`e seus respectivos valores sejam 99000-000 e 123.456.789-10, e elas sejam propriedades do mesmo objeto, como faço para percorrer as 2 propriedades e efetuar um replace nos caracteres `.` e `-`, substituindo por um `''` de forma dinâmica, como se fosse uma função, de forma que eu não precise fazer isso manualmente, propriedade por propriedade, até porque no código que estou trabalhando somente um dos objetos possui 72 propriedades

Comment: Testa `obj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((novoObj, key) => ((novoObj[key] = obj[key].replace(/[\.\-]/g, '')), novoObj), {});` é isso que procuras?

Comment: É exatamente isso, coloque como resposta para que eu possa aceitar ; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens duas opções:

- mudar o objeto internamente
- criar um novo objeto e sobrepor ao antigo

No teu caso não faz diferença pois os valores das chaves são strings. Mas se fossem outros objetos a primeira abordagem poderia ser problemática pois ia mudar objetos que podiam ter referências noutras partes do código.

No teu caso podes fazer assim:

```
obj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((novoObj, key) => {
    novoObj[key] = obj[key].replace(/[\.\-]/g, '');
    return novoObj;
}, {});
```

Comment: Vou criar um objeto novo e mandar ele para o servidor. Muito obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: E qual método uso para verificar se a propriedade tem algum desses caracteres citados acima?? `match()`, `includes()`??

Comment: @LeonardoEbert se for 1 a 1 o includes é mais prático. Senão  o match pode er ambos e só precisas de verificar 1 vez

Comment: Ok, já consegui implementar isso